# Activity result from org.cyanogenmod.focal

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera-intent

I currently use this code to call the camera activity with a result which works fine.

```
      Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
      intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(stockT.getText().toString().toUpperCase()))); 
      startActivityForResult(intent, 10);
```

I recently flashed latest cyanogenmod 10.2-20130915 and now I no longer have access to some of the stock camera features. I want to use org.cyanogenmod.focal to take the photos, since it supports so many features that I want and need.

**Question**

Is this possible to use a third party app like focal to return images as a result if so could you post some code to help me out?

**Background**  (in case of another solution):

This app is used by me only. The app scans VINs and creates folder on the sdcard based on the stock number of the vehicle. I then use the camera intnet to take images and once returned the app shrinks them down to a specific size and jpg quality and saves them into their specific folder. Once I am finished with a set of vehicles I simply click a button and the adjusted images are uploaded to our server and pushed out to our vendors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the focal developers are going to actually include this activity. It is actually missing now so when the app is called it just opens like normal since it does not yet support this feature.